# Unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x108b08740

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I can't fix this error. Help me please.

P.S Im trying to lock view controller by Face ID or Touch ID only.

```
import UIKit
import LocalAuthentication

class ViewController123: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func touchID(_ sender: Any) {

        let context:LAContext = LAContext()

        if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, error: nil)
        {
            context.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthentication, localizedReason: "Login", reply: { (wasCorrect, error) in
                if wasCorrect {
                    print("OK")
                }
                else
                {
                    print("F")
                }
            })
        }
        else
        {
            //This device does not support Face ID or Touch ID
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also please share more data from the crash logs, since it would help identify what method you are trying to call, making the app to crash?

Comment: 2019-02-28 19:24:48.169185+0400 AppName[26255:6011392] [Accessibility] ****************** Loading GAX Client Bundle ****************
2019-02-28 19:24:48.725226+0400 AppName[26255:6011392] Unknown class ViewController123 in Interface Builder file.
2019-02-28 19:24:50.786684+0400 AppName[26255:6011392] -[UIViewController touchID:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x108b08740

Comment: Remove the @IBAction connection from the storyboard and recreate it.

Comment: @AlexV. Please go to the storyboard in which you have wired up ViewController123 and make sure that the class corresponding to the view controller in the storyboard is ViewController123.